# Finding the "triangular root" of a number.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A triangular number is a number that is the sum of the natural numbers up to some $n$. The closed form is $x = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. How do I get $n$ on one side? I've been looking at it from every angle, and I can't find out how. Any help?

Comment: Do you know the quadratic formula?

Answer (score 9):

The answer elsewhere in this thread is of course correct, but for actual calculation there is a simpler answer.  We have $x = \frac12(n^2 +n)$  where $x$ is known and we want to find $n$.  This is equivalent to $$2x+\frac14 = \left(n+\frac12\right)^2$$ or, neglecting the fractions, which I could justify with a more careful analysis, but won't, $$n\approx \sqrt{2x}.$$

And indeed the formula $$n = \left\lfloor\sqrt{2x}\right\rfloor$$ always gives the correct answer.  ($\lfloor\ldots\rfloor$ just means to drop the fraction.)

Comment: You might want to prove that it always gives the correct answer. Nice trick though :)

Comment: I thought it might be more fun if I left it as an exercise.

Comment: You might want to check the answer by substituting it back in the original formula though, since this is going to give an integer always. Nice trick +1. :)

Comment: Very nice trick. A funny way to think about it: if $x$ is the area of an equilateral triangle, $2x$ is the area of a rhombus and $\sqrt{2x}$, its side.

Answer (score 8):

$$n^2+n=2x$$

$$n^2 +n - 2x = 0$$

$$n = \frac{-1 +\sqrt{1+8x}}{2}\text{ provided $n \in \mathbb N,$ otherwise undefined}$$

---

For anyone unfamiliar, see [proof.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula#Derivation_of_the_formula)

Comment: Ah, how did I forget about the quadratic formula? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're very welcome. :)

Comment: This also proves that $1+8x$ must be a perfect square.

Comment: @Sawarnik yes, that condition is necessary and sufficient, since for all integers $x$, $1+8x$ is odd, and therefore, $\sqrt{1+8x}$ is odd and thus, $n \in \mathbb Z$